# How can a parent element invoke a function defined on a child element?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a class-based component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {...}
    constructor(props) {...}
    functionIWantToCall() {...}
    render() {...}
}
```

That is incorporated into the DOM something along the lines of:

```
<div id="parent-div-with-controls">
  .... (some control elements) ....
  <MyComponent {...props}/>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can call a method defined in `MyComponent` from `parent-div-with-controls`?

I'm imagining the 'react equivalent' (if such a thing exists) of this:

```
const myComponent = new MyComponent()
myComponent.functionIWantToCall()
```

Or alternatively, is this something that I would never want to do in React?

Comment: You mean calling child component method from parent? why would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ref to have a "connection" with the instance in MyComponent:

In your parent component, do something like:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  innerComponentInstance = React.createRef()

  // sample place where to "contact" the child component
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.innerComponentInstance.functionIWantToCall()
  }

  render() {
    <MyComponent ref={ this.innerComponentInstance } />
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you - now I see what refs are for